# How to kotlin getposition spinner by value with custom object?

Tags: kotlin, spinner

I'm trying to make a spinner with custom objects.
When I do getposition from spinner I get result -1. I do not know the cause

this my code:

Model

```
class User(var name: String?, var mail: String?) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return name.toString()
    }
}
```

Activity

```
val userList = ArrayList<User>()
val user1 = User("Jim","jim@gmail.com")
userList.add(user1)
val user2 = User("John","john@gmail.com")
userList.add(user2)
val user3 = User("peki", "pek@gmail.com")
userList.add(user3)


val adapter = ArrayAdapter<User>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, userList
)
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
spinner.setAdapter(adapter)

val ambilPosisi : Int =  adapter.getPosition(User("peki","pek@gmail.com"))
Toast.makeText(this, (ambilPosisi).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare your `User` class as [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html):

```
data class User(var name: String?, var mail: String?)
```

It will generate `equals()` and `toString()` methods. So you can use it in object comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call

```
adapter.getPosition()
```

On an item that is effectively not in the list that was submitted to the adapter. You are creating a new User instance as a parameter to the function call, which, although has the identical fields with user3, does not refer to the same variable.

Calling

```
adapter.getPosition(user3)
```

Should return the correct index.